# How do you count the number of solutions to simultaneous boolean equations?

Tags: combinatorics

How do you count the number of solution that satisfy the following simultaneous equations ($x_i = \{0,1\}$:
$$x_1 \oplus x_2 \oplus x_4 \oplus x_5 = 0$$
$$x_1 \oplus x_3 \oplus x_4 \oplus x_6 = 0$$
$$x_2 \oplus x_3 \oplus x_4 \oplus x_7 = 0$$

If we had a single equation then we would have for example:

$$x_1 \oplus x_2 \oplus x_4 \oplus x_5 = 0$$

$$ \implies x_1 \oplus x_2 \oplus x_4 \oplus = x_5$$

which would count the number of triplets that are equal to $x_5$. $x_5$ can take both values of 0 and 1 and that covers the whole truth table for an XOR of 3 variables. Meaning, $2^3$ different solutions exists for 1 equation when we fix one value of $x_5$ (I think, I am not even 100% this is right). Since we can fix it for two values, then the answer is $2^3 \times 2 = 2^4$, right?

However, with more equations we risk double counting. For example $2^3+2^3+2^3$  double counts by a lot.

I was wondering, is there a clean way to reason about how to count the number of solutions for this system?

Comment: I misread the problem, sry. I dont know if exists a closed form for this kind of dependancy.

Comment: is there one for at least the special case that I wrote?